# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'storid'

Tags: python, owl, owlready

I am really new with ontologies especially with owlready2. I loaded an Ontology the basic example Pizza and imported I think successfully on python (I checked whether I can see the classes which I can so..)

Than I used the following code to search one class specifically with the method search():

```py
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append(r"C:/Users/AyselenKuru/Desktop/owl_docs/owlpizza.owl")
onto=get_ontology(r"C:/Users/AyselenKuru/Desktop/owl_docs/owlpizza.owl")
onto.load()
am= onto.search_one(is_a= onto.American)
for x in onto.classes():
    print(x)
```

I want to know how can I search/get one specific Class and an Attribute and I get the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AyselenKuru\Desktop\pizza_ex1.py", line 6, in <module>
    am= onto.search_one(is_a = onto.American)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AyselenKuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 395, in search_one
    def search_one(self, **kargs): return self.search(**kargs).first()
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AyselenKuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 364, in search
    else:                                   v2 = v.storid
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'storid'
```

Comment: This might give a start - http://owlready.306.s1.nabble.com/AttributeError-NoneType-object-has-no-attribute-storid-td2936.html#a2942

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved itself, the example owl File had errors with IRI that caused a Problem with the search

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).